# conda install easydict changes my Python version

Tags: python, conda

I created a conda environment for python3. When I install easydict, though, my python version gets downgraded to the system default:

```
conda create -n p3 python=3.6
conda activate p3
python --version       # => 3.6.4
conda install easydict # => PackagesNotFoundError: ...
conda install easydict -c auto
python --version       # => 2.7.2
```

What's going on? How do I correct it?

Comment: I really haven't seen that before in Anaconda, but you could try creating environments? Knocking it down a whole version of Python seems... problematic for the other libraries.

Comment: @roganjosh, it is problematic. I have created multiple environments, but it appears that I need an environment with *both* easydict and python3.

Comment: AH, I misread what was going on. easydict didn't upgrade to Python 3. It looks dead, so I'm not sure a Py3 version exists. Is there a replacement?

Comment: I'm not sure. But I have at last found that I can install it with pip and get the system working: `pip3 install easydict`

Comment: `conda install tensorflow-gpu==1.11`, installing tensorflow with conda just downgraded my python. `The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

    gdal:                2.1.0-py35_0              --> 2.0.0-py27_1             
    libgdal:             2.1.0-0                   --> 2.0.0-1                  
    python:              3.5.2-0                   --> 2.7.15-h9bab390_6`

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing. "conda install -c auto easydict" will output (among other things)

```
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
    python:              3.6.8-h0371630_0               --> 2.7.16-h9bab390_0
```

Solution: Use "conda install -c conda-forge easydict". In my case, it only slightly downgraded the openssl package, which I can live with.